# Pattern to create new object with type that depends on the type of another object?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have something like this:

```
interface IProduct { }

class ProductA : IProduct { }

class ProductB : IProduct { }

....

interface IViewModel { }

class ProductAViewModel : IViewModel { }

class ProductBViewModel : IViewModel { }
```

And now I want to be able to create instances of my ViewModels without knowing real type of products:

```
IProduct prod = new ProductA();
IViewModel vm = someFactoryOrBuilderObject.CreateViewModel(prod);
// real type of vm depends on the product's type
// if prod is ProductA, vm must be ProductAViewModel
...
DisplayViewModel(VM); // working with VM as IViewModel (regardless of it's real type)
```

Goals:

- Type of ViewModel must be resolved at runtime.
- Adding new products and viewmodels to my app should NOT require any changes to the existing code.

Which is the best way to implement this functionality?
There are some obvious ways, but they are not satisfying:

- Creating something like map (dictionary) of types (productType<->vmType). But when I'd want to add some more products, I will have to change this map.
- Creating a factory method like GetViewModel() inside every product class. But this insanely violates SOLID's SRP.
- Creating a Factory or Builder. But these patterns don't cover my requirements.

Comment: Anyway there will be some place where you need to "link" viewmodel and product.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right :( .  I was just trying to stick SOLID's OCP.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: If you are after a good pattern then you might want to take a leaf out _Windows Shell Namespace Extensions_ and _Microsoft Management Console_ and see how they work under the hood

Comment: What you are proposing is probably a bad design anyway.  What happens when your Model needs to appear in many different types of ViewModels?  I might have a `Patient` that needs to appear in both `DemographicViewModel` and `PrescriptionViewModel`  It's rare than a single entity type has a 1:1 to a View Model.  The same **isn't** true for Views and ViewModels however.  I know of frameworks that automatically determine the V from the VM or vice versa.  Perhaps that is what you are thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning: This may not be a good design pattern to follow.**

In practice, the dependency chain should be `View` => `ViewModel` => `Model` (`=>` means "depends on"). The `Model` shall not know anything about the `ViewModel` (i.e. through attributes, in the code below).

The answer below is just an accommodation for what you have requested in the question.

---

I don't think there is really "clean" ways you can do this without using reflection. However, we can make the rest of the code clean using reflection (the price of which is to use reflection :) ).

I now propose a solution using attributes.

**Remember: this method only works if you have a public constructor for every `ViewModel` class that takes a one `Product` object as parameter!** If not, Varun's solution would be better (you need a mapping function anyway in this case).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
sealed class UseViewModelAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ViewModelType { get; }
    public UseViewModelAttribute(Type viewModelType)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeof(IViewModel).IsAssignableFrom(viewModelType));
        ViewModelType = viewModelType;
    }
}

class ViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly static Type[] ctorParams = new Type[] { typeof(IProduct) };
    public IViewModel CreateViewModel(IProduct product)
    {
        var vmType = (product.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(attr
            => attr is UseViewModelAttribute) as UseViewModelAttribute)?.ViewModelType;
        Debug.Assert(!(vmType is null));
        return Activator.CreateInstance(vmType, product) as IViewModel;
    }
}
```

To use this, add a `UseViewModel(typeof(ViewModelForThisProductType))` before your `Product` classes. Like:

```
[UseViewModel(typeof(ProductAViewModel))]
class ProductA : IProduct { }

[UseViewModel(typeof(ProductBViewModel))]
class ProductB : IProduct { }
```

Your `ViewModel` classes should look like:

```
class ProductAViewModel : IViewModel {
    //You can use both IProduct or the derived type (i.e ProductA) as the constructor param
    public ProductAViewModel(ProductA a)
    {

    }
}

class ProductBViewModel : IViewModel {
    public ProductBViewModel(IProduct b)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I can see two things wrong with this.  **1)** What happens if a model needs to be shown in more than one ViewModel?  It's rare that there is a 1:1 between model & VM **2)** You are polluting your models with attributes purely for the VM's benefit.  In a canonical data model system, the WCF or network layer may not care about these attributes

Comment: @MickyD I agree this is a bad design. Views should know about their view models, and the view models should know about their model, not the reverse. But this is what the OP asked for. I will edit the answer to indicate that this is not a good design.

Comment: That’s true, it is what the OP asked for and is a reasonable solution.  +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it purely at run-time, the only option I see is mapping by name convention. Inside CreateViewModel, you'll search something like this:

```
IViewModel CreateViewModel(IProduct product)
{
    var vmType = Assembly.getTypes().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == $"{product.GetType().Name}ViewModel");

    // Create instance of vmType and perform mapping of properties between product and vm using reflection based on name convention. Automapper can do this for you as well.
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking of reflection too, but it is the last thing I'd want to use in my case. I want somewhat 'clean' architecture.

Comment: @Vladimir all "clean" architecture frameworks and libraries using reflection.